# Build on Xcode 12 showing 'Any iOS Device(armv7, arm64)'

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, xcode12

I migrated my existing project to Xcode12. I had to remove `VALID_ARCHS` from Build Settings.
And added `arm64` for `Excluded Architecture` (`Any iOS simulator SDK`). Then I am able to run app on iOS14 simulator.

But now while creating archive it is showing.

```
Any iOS Device(armv7, arm64)
```

Please refer this screenshot.

[image]

In previous Xcode it was showing `Generic iOS Device`

Does this mean app will not support all iOS Phones?

Comment: arm64 is the current 64-bit ARM CPU architecture, as used since the iPhone 5S and later. It means the app will support all iOS Phones since the iPhone 5S.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To my knowledge, this has been updated in the latest Xcode. The previous one (11.XX) was with `Generic IOS device`, however this version has it written as `Any IOS device`. So it is indexed capable of running on all devices with the correct IOS installed. See here my screenshot

[image: Any_IOS_device]